# Svg element rotate

Tags: svg, raphael

I'm trying to rotate an SVG object. I found some tutorials or questions there, but for my, it does not worked.

1. I have svg with text or path element.
2. arround the element, there is some handlers for move, delete.. rotate
3. What I need: When I drag on handler element for rotate with selected element and move with mouse, element should rotate accordingly, on which side i move with mouse.

Yust the same function as in the Raphael free transform plugin.

code:

```
<text style="text-anchor: middle; font: 20px Arial;" x="0" y="0" text-anchor="middle" font="10px "Arial"" stroke="#000000" fill="#000000" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,226,240)" font-family="Arial" stroke-width="1" font-size="20px">
<path style="" fill="none" stroke="#000000" d="M192.95000076293945,228L258.7833366394043,228L258.7833366394043,252L192.95000076293945,252L192.95000076293945,228" stroke-dasharray="4,3">
<image x="171.95000076293945" y="207" width="21" height="21" preserveAspectRatio="none" href="image/ico/drag.png">
<image x="258.7833366394043" y="207" width="21" height="21" preserveAspectRatio="none" href="image/ico/rotate.png">
<image x="258.7833366394043" y="252" width="21" height="21" preserveAspectRatio="none" href="image/ico/scale.png">
<image x="171.95000076293945" y="252" width="21" height="21" preserveAspectRatio="none" href="image/ico/delete.png">
```

text is the element for rotate.
path is frame for the selected element.
image elements are handlers for action like move... rotate.

I spend a lot of time on this with no results. Thanks for any help!

Comment: If possible, can you include the javascript along with it, as thats the key bit. Just wondering, why don't you use Raphael freetransform you mention, as thats probably the most comprehensive and solid solution.

Comment: I'm not using RFT because transform this plugin to right template is probably more dificult than create new.  My solution for this never worked, so I deleted it couple days ago and now I'm trying to do this again with clean head